# Setting an enum by int value

Tags: java, android, enums

I have an enum with an `int` value for storage in a DB:

```
public enum DayType {
    REGULAR(1), VACATION(2), SICK(3);

    private final int value;
    private DayType(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here is a setter for this enum:

```
private DayType dayType

public void setDayType(int dayType) {

     switch(dayType) {
        case 1:
            this.dayType = DayType.REGULAR;
            break;

        case 2:
            this.dayType = DayType.VACATION;
            break;

        case 3:
            this.dayType = DayType.SICK;
            break;

        default :
            this.dayType = DayType.REGULAR;
            break;
    }
```

Everything works just fine. But there has to be a more "pretty" way to write the setter if there is a `int` value for each enum value. Without using switch case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you don't need to explicitly specify int value for each element, but just treat its constants as array:

```
private DayType dayType = DayType.REGULAR;
public void setDayType(int dayType) {
   if (dayType <= DayType.values().length) this.dayType = DayType.values()[dayType - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to add a static method in the enum

```
public enum DayType {
    REGULAR(1), VACATION(2), SICK(3);

    private final int value;
    private DayType(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static DayType byValue(int value) {
        Arrays.stream(DayType.values())
            .filter(dt -> dt.value == value)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(DayType.REGULAR);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
private DayType dayType

public void setDayType(int dayType) {
    this.dayType = DayType.byValue(dayType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the values of .ordinal() and values[index] to acess the values.

Instead of having the value field in the enum, store its DayType.REGULAR.ordinal()  value.

So to load:

```
this.dayTipe = DayType.values[dayType];
```

The only downside here is to update the Enum, you need to add all new ones after the last one, so its indexes never conflicts.

Comment: Except `Enum#values()` is a method, and `dayType` is 1-based, and it may be out of range for the values which should return REGULAR.

Comment: The idea here is not to use the value as a key, and the same ordinal will be the same values

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid use of switch statement by using

```
public void setDayType(int type) {

    for(DayType dayType : DayType.values()) {
        if(dayType.getValue() == type) {
            this.dayType = dayType;
        }
    }
}
```

If you needed performance rather than memory you can use `HashMap`:

```
private HashMap<Integer, DayType> dayTypes;

private void initDayTypes() {

    for(DayType type : DayType.values()) {
        dayTypes.put(type.value, type);
    }
}
```

Usage will be the next:

```
public void setDayType(int type) {

    this.dayType = dayTypes.get(type);
}
```